# How can I add a .png watermark to a graph made on matplotlib?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I'd like to add a watermark over charts using matplotlib (but under the lines/points/bars plotted), using a .png image. I'm having trouble doing this without ruining the graph in the process.

The following code makes a simple chart in matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def MakePlotWithWatermark():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10, 5))
    ax.grid(True, which='both', axis='both', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)
    ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 9, 16, 25], marker='o', color = "Blue")
    plt.close()
    return fig
```

This works as expected, giving this as [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9V9W.png).

However, I want to add a watermark to the chart. For the sake of example, I'll use a picture of a smiley face. I modify my function as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

def MakePlotWithWatermark():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10, 5))
    ax.grid(True, which='both', axis='both', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)
    ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 9, 16, 25], marker='o', color = "Blue")
    
    PathToWatermark = "SmileyWatermark.png"
    img = mpimg.imread(PathToWatermark)
    ax.imshow(img, alpha=0.1)
    
    plt.close()
    return fig
```

Now, [the resulting chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxemQ.png) doesn't show the data properly.

How can I add the watermark, without changing anything else about the plot?

I have tried the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73254396/how-do-i-put-a-watermark-behind-plotted-data-using-matplotlib): this is the [resulting output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDU50.png) If possible, I'd like the whole watermark to be visible, and as close to centered in the plot as it can get. I would also like to keep the color scheme the same.

I have also tried the answer from [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75191556/21053860), with [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh2Qs.png). I suspect that resizing our watermark to match the size and shape of the plot area will get a perfect solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put a watermark behind plotted data using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73254396/how-do-i-put-a-watermark-behind-plotted-data-using-matplotlib)

Comment: It makes some progress. However, the image is now too large and not entirely visible. I also need the face color to remain the same, the color scheme is important here. I can't seem to attach an image to this comment. I'll edit the initial post to show the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from matplotlib.offsetbox import ( OffsetImage, AnchoredOffsetbox, AnnotationBbox)


def MakePlotWithWatermark():
    
    img_rep = requests.get('https://i.ibb.co/6YLhH1N/Untitled-1.jpg')
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_rep.content))
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10, 5))
    ax.grid(True, which='both', axis='both', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)
    ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 9, 16, 25], marker='o', color = "Blue")
    
    imagebox = OffsetImage(img, zoom=0.5, alpha=0.2)
    imagebox.image.axes = ax
    
    #ao = AnchoredOffsetbox(4, pad=0.01, borderpad=0, child=imagebox)  # method 1
    ao = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, (0.5, 0.5), xycoords='axes fraction', bboxprops={'lw':0})  # method 2
    ao.patch.set_alpha(0)
    ax.add_artist(ao)
    
    plt.close()
    return fig

MakePlotWithWatermark()
```

[image]

Comment: This is very close. It slightly expands the image margins, however, which is a problem. Is there some way to detect the size of the plot area, and automatically rescale the image to that same size before adding it to the plot? I've edited the original post showing the output.

Comment: do you want the image at the center or what ??